# How to change ANY text when click on it? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want any text on the site to change to 'Ok!' when I click on it.

[image]
[image]

I tried using this code:

```
if($('*').text() != ''){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).text('Ok!');
    });
}
```

But it does not work because if the text is in a div it changes when I click anywhere in div, but I need that only when I click on the text.

Comment: There isn't any way to my knowledge to only target the text of a div, maybe wrap the text in order to get it to a more specific point. Are you saying you only want the text to change when you click on the literal pixels of the character?

Comment: @Laif *There isn't any way to my knowledge to only target the text of a div,* <-- Of course there is: `.textContent`

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm referring to a click event triggered only on clicking the literal characters of something as he is describing, not fetching the text.

Comment: Do you have a working example of code to share in a snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Laif The answer is yes for that too. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help on another site: https://qna.habr.com/q/698485

Code that solves the problem:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if(
    selection.focusOffset 
    && selection.focusNode 
    && selection.focusNode.nodeType == 3 
    && selection.focusNode.length !== selection.focusOffset 
    ) selection.focusNode.data = 'OK!';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to have each and every word isolated into its own `span` element. Then, it's just a matter of adding a `click` event to all the spans.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Word Swap</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum
    deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non
    provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum
    fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta
    nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
    omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis
    debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae
    non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus
    maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </main>
  <script>
   // Get all the text anywhere in the main
   let main = document.querySelector("main");
   let text = main.textContent;

   // Break up the text where there are spaces and turn into an array
   let words = text.split(/\s+/g);

   // wrap each word in its own span
   let wrappedWords = words.map(function(word){
     return "<span>" + word + "</span>";
   });

   // Replace the body text content with the wrapped words
   main.innerHTML = wrappedWords.join(" ");

   // Set up click event on document
   document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
     // Test to see if it was a span that was clicked
     if(event.target.nodeName === "SPAN"){
       // Replace the span contents
       event.target.textContent = "OK!";
     }
   });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Laif Uh, yeah. It's a work-around called a solution to the problem because it's the only way to accomplish it. There's nothing wrong with this approach. No need to down vote because you didn't think of it.

Comment: Simply responding to your comment, I literally said there was no way to do it, hence the reason you needed to make a work around in order to accomplish it.

Comment: @Laif ???!!! If there's no way to do it, then how did I do it? LOL. I don't think you quite understand that programming is nothing but problem solving.

Comment: As I initially stated, there is no way to target the text of a div individually using jquery. You instead had to modify the DOM, giving each word it's own element and therefore completely breaking from my statement. You did it, congrats, however I still have yet to see a way to accomplish what I said. To quote the answer to the post this was marked as a duplicate for: "Since we cannot listen for events directly on the textNodes themselves, we have to take a more creative path to solving the problem."

Comment: @Laif But again, the statement *there is no way to target the text of a div individually* is incorrect. You target the text of a `div` with `.textContent`. Perhaps you meant something else, but my response was to that literal (and incorrect) statement.

Comment: I clarified what I meant in the next comment, to do so again however: I am intending to state that there is no way in native jquery to select a part of a div's text content based on where you click, nor to target said text based on the literal pixel map of the characters.

Comment: @Laif And again, perhaps you meant something else, but your next comment was also incorrect as I read it. Maybe just work on being clearer in what you are trying to convey. Also, you're comments didn't say anything about JQuery (I have no idea what you mean by "native JQuery" since there is no such thing. Again, clarity needed.).